# Sequence of functions which converges point-wise to one value but converges in the mean to another?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

What is an example of a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ on [0,1] such that it converges pointwise to $g_1$ but it converges in the mean to $g_2$?

Comment: What is the norm?

Comment: It does not specify.

Comment: Take any uniformly sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}$ to, say $g_1$. Then, modifies $g_1$ by a set of cero measure. Then $\{f_n\}$ will be convergent in mean to $g_1$ and to $g_2$, but $g_2\neq g_1$.